# Can't download from GitHub

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, wget

Trying to get the following file from GitHub and the file does not download'''!wget -P {HOME}/weights -q [https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov9/releases/tag/v0.1.1/yolov9-c.pt'''](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov9/releases/tag/v0.1.1/yolov9-c.pt%27%27%27)

I know they are there.

'''https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov9/releases/tag/v0.1/yolo9-c.pt'''

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have added an extra '1' in `v0.1` at the URL. Also, the correct URL path is a bit different as well

`wget -P $HOME/weights -q https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov9/releases/download/v0.1/yolov9-c.pt`

Try the above and it should work

Comment: WHat I get for working late!!! Thanks so much!!!!!!